# Getting file move datetime

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, filesystems, fileinfo

When you copy a file (in a windows environment), the Creation and LastAccess datetime are modified and can be retrieved with a `FileInfo` object.

However, I can't find any reliable datetime (directly linked to a file) that would be changed when a file is moved into a folder.  Does windows update any datetime value in the file when it's moved (and can it be retrieved)?

**Note**
I'm not in a dead end and I have many workarounds.  I'm just wondering if this could be handled directly at the file level to avoid unnecessary logic.

Comment: Are you saying when you copy the file from one directory to another directory on the same machine the Creation and LastAccess datetime get modified? That is odd!!

Comment: Yes, it is.  The oddest part is that the modification datetime remains the same so you end up with a modification datetime before the creation datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this seems to be how this works in Windows:

- **Creation time:** if the target file already exists, its' creation time is preserved, otherwise it is set to the current system time.
- **Last Modification time:** always copied from modification time of the source file.
- **Last Access time:** always set to the current system time.

[RoboCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx) and [RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) are couple of command-line tools that can preserve the mtime for directories with the /DCOPY:T switch, but this only works in Vista and newer.
Another copy utility which can preserve timestamps is [XXCOPY](http://www.xxcopy.com/)

You can find some example for RoboCopy at the end of this page: 
http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm