# C# How to get the date that the file was put into a folder?

Tags: c#

Assume, on Sunday `file.txt` file is created, saved in folder `folder1`.

On Monday, someone copied or moved `file.txt` to a folder `folder2`.

On Tuesday, For file `Folder2/file.txt`, I want to get the date when the file came to `folder2` (ie date Monday)

**UPDATE:**
`FileInfo.LastAccessTime` prop, is not affected when moving a file from folder to another, but only when copy paste file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FileSystemInfo.LastAccessTime` Property

Refer to the msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`File.SetCreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime.aspx) to set copied time.

```
File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
File.SetCreationTime(destinationFile, DateTime.Now);
```

**Update :**

Since question is updated to know (only)date when the file is copied manually, we just need to know when the file was `Created` or `LastAccessed`. You could do this.

```
var f = new FileInfo("destinationfile");
DateTime lastAccess = f.LastAccessTime
string datoftheweek = lastAccess.ToString("ddd");
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain myself correctly, I edited the question again.
I will not forward the file myself to folder2, someone moves. I just need to get the date of the transfer ..

Comment: Still with this code you can identify when(Day/Date) copy was taken place, right?

Comment: The file is delivered by hand, not by machine.
My code runs only when the file is already in the folder folder2

Comment: @Refael Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: @Heri, LastAccessed, does not return the time the file was transferred to the folder.

Comment: @Refael it does on windows platform, I just tested it. When you copy and paste the file, windows will update creation time and lastaccesed time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106438/discussion-between-refael-and-hari-prasad).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access chat in office :-(

Comment: Try to move file, not copy paste.

Comment: @Refael I got what you mean, when the file is moved it won't update those properties, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558159/getting-file-move-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

```
Action        CreationTime       LastWriteTime      LastAccessTime            FullName
        2016/2/17 23:32:09  2016/2/17 23:43:06  2016/2/17 23:43:06         D:\Temp\tmp
CopyTo  2016/3/16 17:57:00  2016/2/17 23:43:06  2016/3/16 17:57:00   D:\Temp\Test\tmp1
MoveTo  2016/2/17 23:32:09  2016/2/17 23:43:06  2016/2/17 23:43:06   D:\Temp\Test\tmp2
```

I use `FileInfo` to test the file.
`CopyTo` will change the `CreationTime` and `LastAccessTime`, but `MoveTo` not change any of the three attributes.

When the file be copied to destination folder, we can use `CreationTime` to detect the copied time.
I have no idea to detect the time when the file was moved, maybe the folder's `LastAccessTime` can be used sometimes.

If it is possible, use `FileSystemWatcher` to watch for changes in a special directory, then save the time of file changed.