# How to get names of files in a folder moved on a particular date in windows using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am coding using C# and .NET on VS 2012.

There is a server which cuts 2-3 files onto a folder on my computer everyday at 3 AM. I need a program which gets the filename and extension of the file moved on the current day.
I have tried numerous methods like -

```
DirectoryInfo filepath = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Gaurav\\Desktop\\RandomFolder");

FileInfo[] files = filepath.GetFiles("*.txt");

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
   if (file.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Today)
    {
       filecount++;
    }
}
```

However, file.LastWriteTime gives the date it was last written to. Other methods like file.CreationTime gives the date when it was created which might not be the same as the date it was moved to the folder on my computer. Is there a way to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:** I have no control over the server so I cannot add a timestamp when it is moved to my computer.

Comment: Yes there is a way: Put a time stamp when you move any file.

Comment: @FirstStep I have no control over the server so I cannot add a timestamp when it is moved to my computer unfortunately.

Comment: Okay just please provide a [MCVE]. What is `file` and what is `filepath`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558159/getting-file-move-datetime

Comment: @FirstStep Updated.

Comment: @HaitamZanid I saw the post. Is there a way to do it without external tools?

Comment: @Gaurav Lath i don't think so

Comment: You could create a FileSystemWatcher event listener on the directory that the files were being copied to, and then change the name or the createDate property when they were added to the directory.

Comment: You can actually watch the directory and detect new files and you can handle everything

Answer (score 1):

If you only have control over the target machine you could create a service to watch the directory and then time stamp the file at that point.  Here is a decent example of how to create a directory watch service: [Creating a Service to Monitor a Directory](http://www.rhyous.com/2012/11/27/c-creating-a-service-to-monitor-a-directory/)

Then you could change the event listener methods around to your liking, but I think that changing the file name or resetting the creation time using `System.IO.File.SetCreationTime(path, time);` would be a good option. Something like:

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds); 
if (File.Exists(path))
     File.SetCreationTime(path, time);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't really practical.   The attributes of a file that is moved (within the same volume) don't change.  This is different that what happens when you copy a file.

However, there is a way to write a program that "keeps watch" over a folder and can detect when ever a file is added, modified, or deleted.  This approach would require that the app to be running on the server at the time of the activity.

If you're interested in this approach, let us know and we can steer you to good examples of the `FileSystemWatcher` class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396